# Resolving view from webflow when running app with run-web

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, spring-webflow

I have grails app that uses plugins to modularize app. Structure of app is as follows:

- pluginA
- pluginB
- pluginMain

On one of those plugins (say pluginA) I have controller that uses Spring Webflow (using Spring Webflow 2.0.8.1).

Plugins are resolved locally in BuildConfig.groovy of pluginMain (grails.plugin.location.'pluginA' = "../pluginA"
grails.plugin.location.'pluginB' = "../pluginB").

When running app with **run-app** views used by webflow are resloved OK.

But, when I run app with **run-war** controller from pluginA tries to resolve view from location **pluginMain**/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/*controllerName*/*flowName*/*nameOfView*.jsp instead from **pluginA**
so I am getting HTTP 404 not found error.

I am using grails 2.3.7 and java jdk 1.7.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location that it is looking for in the run-war situation is the standard location for resolving page and flow views. You are likely getting into trouble by attempting to create a war file using inline plugins (the grails.plugin.location).

The inline plugin support is really nice when developing plugin functionality, but it has its quirks, particularly when you get multiple dependent plugins in play.  At some point you have to break down and start publishing your plugins.

Try publishing the plugin to your local Maven repository using the "maven-install" command. Then change your BuildConfig.groovy file to reference the installed version of the plugin.

My normal workflow is something like this:

1. Develop the new plugin functionality using an inline plugin definition in BuildConfig.groovy, testing with run-app and run-test until I'm happy.
2. Publish a SNAPSHOT version of the plugin (ie. 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT) and update BuildConfig.groovy to point to the snapshot and test using run-app and run-war eg:

   compile (":ark-kpi:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT")
3. Publish your plugin in release form either to your local maven repository (maven-install) or a public repository like a locally running Artifactory if you want to share with colleagues (publish-plugin).

You should read the guide section on plugins and configuration for details on setting up repositories.

Comment: I did as you suggested but the result is the same. I even upgraded project to grails 2.4.3 and new version of webflow 2.1. Somehow, webflow view is resolved using path /WEB-INF/grails-app/views/controller/flowName/page.gsp

Comment: OK, it must have something to do with the pluginMain bit then. Usually you would have your application specific artefacts (domains, controllers, services, views) in the application with one or more shared functionality pieces in plugins. It is somewhat unusual to place your application logic into a plugin as well. Having said that, it should still work. It definitely works for us and we make heavy use of plugins with webflows embedded in them. I can't really offer more guidance except to try moving the pluginMain logic back to the application and see if that corrects it.

Comment: I finally figured it out. The problem was in naming my webflow’s views. My views were named lowercase but in controller webflow closure names were camel case (e.g. brandSelection{…}, view name was brandselection.gsp). It somehow worked when running app with run-app but when app was packaged inside war view could not be resolved. Just one note: pluginMain is actually application itself not a plugin, I named it incorrectly in example. 
Anyway, much appreciate your help and advices.